# Creating chart with day-of-year time series for multiple regions using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, chart

I'm trying to create a chart of NDVI values that shows the average values for each day of the year for the last 5 years. I think exactly what I need is this:
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/charts_image_collection#uichartimagedoyseriesbyregion

But if I insert a custom feature.collection with two points selected, it only shows one line in the chart, not two. What is the problem?

```
var pts = ee.FeatureCollection("users/petrjanos/hlavni/random_points");

// Load MODIS vegetation indices data and subset a decade of images.
var vegIndices = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A1')
                     .filter(ee.Filter.date('2010-01-01', '2020-01-01'))
                     .select(['NDVI', 'EVI']);

// Define the chart and print it to the console.
var chart = ui.Chart.image
                .doySeriesByRegion({
                  imageCollection: vegIndices,
                  bandName: 'NDVI',
                  regions: pts,
                  regionReducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                  scale: 500,
                  //yearReducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                  seriesProperty: 'label',
                  startDay: 1,
                  endDay: 365
                })
                .setOptions({
                  title: 'Average NDVI Value by Day of Year',
                  hAxis: {
                    title: 'Day of year',
                    titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
                  },
                  vAxis: {
                    title: 'NDVI (x1e4)',
                    titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
                  },
                  lineWidth: 5,
                  colors: ['f0af07', '0f8755', '76b349'],
                });
print(chart);
```

My feature collection: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/petrjanos/hlavni/random_points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in the `ui.Chart.image.doySeriesByRegion`, the `seriesProperty` argument is set to 'label'. However, that property does not exist in your `FeatureCollection`. Try changing it to a property that exists in your `FeatureCollection` such as 'id'.

```
var chart = ui.Chart.image
                .doySeriesByRegion({
                  imageCollection: vegIndices,
                  bandName: 'NDVI',
                  regions: pts,
                  regionReducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                  scale: 500,
                  // Here's the change
                  seriesProperty: 'id',
                  startDay: 1,
                  endDay: 365
                })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! ..and one more question: if I use Landsat 8 data with filtering (clouds and shadows), can I get continuous lines and not just point like in the picture? https://imgur.com/C074rOo

Comment: Hmm its hard to help without a reprex, I would suggest posting another question in SO about this issue.